# Nginx Rewrite Multiple Query Parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, query-string

I am having problems creating a rewrite rule that match my .htaccess on Nginx, I am hoping someone can point me to the right direction.

My .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|app|assets|upload|api)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|) index.php?class=$1&action=$2&param=$3 [L]
```

My nginx configuration

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|) /index.php?class=$1&action=$2&param=$3 break;
}
```

Query params are optional for example:

```
site.com/
site.com/customers
site.com/customers/add
site.com/customers/edit/1
```

I cannot rewrite the app code since iam only migrating from apache to nginx.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could structure the solution like this:

```
root /path/to/root;
index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|) /index.php?class=$1&action=$2&param=$3 last;
    return 404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;

    # fastcgi stuff
}
```

I have not checked your regular expression. The `try_files` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files).